# How to put a text bottom right of image

Tags: css

[image: position]
Image will be aligned to center and text will be aligned to left of `div`.

I tried text aligned but text goes to start of page

```css
/*Photos*/

.Cameraphoto {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.Cameraphoto p {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!-- photo -->
<div class="Cameraphoto">
  <img src="imgss/picture.jpeg">
  <p>
    Paragraph
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your codes with us.

Comment: I am confused -  the title talks of placing the text 'bottom right of image' but your text talks of 'text aligned to the left of div'. Which is it that you require?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you,
A bit of code would have helped more.
Maybe try putting the image in one element `img`, and the text in another element `div / span`.
And both will have the same father element for example `div`.

something like this:

```
<div class="father">
    <img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
    <div class="image-text"> your text </div>
</div>
```

You will give one style to your text element and another style to the image element.

```
img{
text-align: center;
}
.image-text{
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: it does not work. with this image goes to right too